# What would be the fastest way to generate persistentVolume, persistentVolumeClaim, and storageClass correct yaml file from kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes

Two years ago while I took CKA exam, I already have this question. At that time I only could do was to see k8s.io official documentation. Now just curious on generating pv / pvc / storageClass via pure kubectl cli. What I look for is similar to the similar logic as deployment, for example:

```
$ kubectl create deploy test --image=nginx --port=80 --dry-run -o yaml
W0419 23:54:11.092265   76572 helpers.go:553] --dry-run is deprecated and can be replaced with --dry-run=client.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Or similar logic to run a single pod:

```
$ kubectl run test-pod --image=nginx --port=80 --dry-run -o yaml
W0419 23:56:29.174692   76654 helpers.go:553] --dry-run is deprecated and can be replaced with --dry-run=client.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: test-pod
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: test-pod
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

So what should I type in order to generate pv / pvc / storageClass yaml? The current only declarative fastest way:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
<PV / PVC / storageClass yaml goes here>
EOF
```

Edited: Please note that I look any fast way to generate correct pv / pvc / storageClass template without remembering specific syntax thru cli, and not necessary via kubectl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Look, bookmark and build index your brain in all yaml files in this Github directory (content/en/examples/pods) before the exam. 100% legal according to CKA curriculum.

https://github.com/kubernetes/website/tree/master/content/en/examples/pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml

Then use this form during exam:

```
kubectl create -f https://k8s.io/examples/pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml
```

In case you need edit and apply:

```
# curl
curl -sL https://k8s.io/examples/pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml -o /your/path/pv-volume.yaml
# wget
wget -O /your/path/pv-volume.yaml https://k8s.io/examples/pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml

vi /your/path/pv-volume.yaml
kubectl apply -f /your/path/pv-volume.yaml
```

### Story:

Actually after look around for my own answer, there's an article floating around that suggest me to bookmark these 100% legal pages:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/

Note that:

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml
```

1. kubectl could create objects from URL
2. Where is the original https://k8s.io pointing to?
3. What else I could benefit from?

Then after digging up the page above "pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml" code, the link points to:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml

Which direct to:

https://github.com/kubernetes/website/tree/master/content/en/examples/pods

So https://k8s.io is a shorten uri as well as a http 301 redirect to https://github.com/kubernetes/website/tree/master/content/en to help the exam candidate easy to produce (not copy-n-paste) in the exam terminal.

Answer (score 3):

There is no kubectl command to create a resource like PV, PVC, and storage class.

> From certificate points of view, you have go over [k8.io](https://kubernetes.io/) and look for the PV, PVC, and storage class under the task link.

> Under task link, most of the YAML will be the same and for now, this is **one of the fastest ways in exam**.